# Parsing "JSON" containing trailing commas

Tags: python, json, malformed

Are there any Python JSON parsers that will cope with trailing commas?

(I'm consuming the "JSON" from an external source and have no control over it.)

Comment: But you do have control over what you do between 1) retrieving the JSON and 2) feeding it to the JSON parser.

Comment: JSON does not contain trailing commas.

Comment: Right, one option would be to try and clean the data before parsing it. I only wondered if there might be a more lenient JSON parser as supposedly some browsers can cope with trailing commas in JSON.

Comment: Report the malformed json to its provider. Its not useful to anyone if they're not outputting it correctly.

Comment: @Acorn: Just because some browsers accept it doesn't mean your code should, too -- that's how non-conforming software gets propagated -- so do what Eric said.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can json.loads ignore trailing commas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23705304/can-json-loads-ignore-trailing-commas)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Grab PyYAML. JSON is a subset of YAML, so a YAML parser should parse most JSON. YAML's grammar allows trailing commas in sequences.

Comment: I did see this suggested somewhere as a solution, but also saw mention of spaces after colons being mandatory, which would make it a lot less useful. After testing it out, it seems that the space isn't mandatory as long as the key is a quoted string. If the JSON has a key that's a number and no space after the colon, it wont parse.

Comment: Im assuming thats pretty rare for a number to be a key, but great job finding that. Maybe mention this functionality to PyYAML maintainers and explain the use-case to them as well.

Comment: That is an awesome little hack, especially for scraping from sources where you cannot control the output. (ie - web scraping)

Comment: "YAML's grammar allows trailing commas in sequences." source? Which part of the spec?

Comment: @MarcH per https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#74-flow-collection-styles (If I understand it correctly) "Flow collection entries are terminated by the “,” indicator. The final “,” may be omitted."

Answer (score 3):

[json-cfg](https://pypi.org/project/json-cfg/) appears to support an extension of JSON that allows it. It also allows comments and unquoted keys.

```
>>> import jsoncfg
>>> jsoncfg.loads('{"key1": "{my tricky value,}", }')
OrderedDict([('key1', '{my tricky value,}')])
```

The extra options (comments and unquoted keys) can be disabled with the [`JSONParserParams`] class:

```
jsoncfg.loads('{"key1": "{my tricky value,}" /*nope*/}', jsoncfg.JSONParserParams(allow_comments=False, allow_unquoted_keys=False))
```

This comes without all the concern about allowing the entire YAML syntax. Furthermore, unlike regex-based preprocessing and overly simple modules such as jsoncomment, it implements a full blown [tokenizer and parser](https://github.com/pasztorpisti/json-cfg/blob/master/src/jsoncfg/parser.py) (as befits a non-regular language) to avoid nesting problems (like when a comma trails a `]` or `}` *inside a string*).

Whether this library is still maintained or not is an open question. It could definitely use a bit more documentation.