# Can json.loads ignore trailing commas?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

As mentioned in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201782/can-you-use-a-trailing-comma-in-a-json-object), you are not allowed to have any trailing commas in json. For example, this

```
{
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2"
}
```

is fine, but this

```
{
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
}
```

is invalid syntax.

For reasons mentioned in [this other StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992559/python-tuple-comma-syntax-rule), using a trailing comma is legal (and perhaps encouraged?) in Python code. I am working with both Python and JSON, so I would love to be able to be consistent across both types of files. Is there a way to have `json.loads` ignore trailing commas?

Comment: In short, no.  The best practices or preferred approaches for one language have no bearing for the best practices in another.

Comment: In JSON, it’s invalid, so no, the JSON parser will report that as an invalid format (correct behavior!). If it’s a Python dictionary, you could parse it using `ast.literal_eval`.

Comment: I don't think so. The json module adheres to the standard. You might be able to hack your own version,  though.

Comment: "I am working with both Python and JSON, so I would love to be able to be consistent across both types of files" - one type of file is JSON. What's the other? Python modules? `print`ed Python data structures?

Comment: The second example you gave isn't JSON, but it is HOCON. https://github.com/typesafehub/config/blob/master/HOCON.md Kind of makes me want to write a parser for python...

Comment: @ChrisMartin - Hmmm, nope.  Skimmed the spec, defines **control-characters** as **from the JSON spec** (big can of " \/worms/ **^I** **^H** ").  It also will not accept numbers starting with a decimal (so  javascript declarations like `{number: .75, number2: .1E2}` would be invalid.  It employs `#` and `//` for comments, but provides no `/* block comment method */`.  Other than that, it's awesome.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing "JSON" containing trailing commas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11052952/parsing-json-containing-trailing-commas)

Comment: use yaml instead - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/63555547/9201239

Comment: @chris-martin: https://github.com/chimpler/pyhocon

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can wrap python's json parser with [jsoncomment](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsoncomment)

> JSON Comment allows to parse JSON files or strings with:
>
> - Single and Multi line comments
> - Multi line data strings
> - Trailing commas in objects and arrays, after the last item

Example usage:

```
import json
from jsoncomment import JsonComment

with open(filename) as data_file:    
    parser = JsonComment(json)
    data = parser.load(data_file)
```

Comment: That package isn't very good. It removes commas from strings as well. Just have a string containing `,}` or `,]` and the commas will magically disappear.

Comment: As @Sven says, here's a test string to demo it: `{"key1": "{my special value,}"}`.

Comment: @Sven Looks like they upgraded to a proper parse and abandoned regex: https://github.com/vaidik/commentjson/releases

Comment: If it has its own full-blown JSON parser why not just return the result of its parsing? This is parsing it, re-encoding it then parsing it again.

Answer (score 20):

Fast forward to 2021, now we have https://pypi.org/project/json5/

A quote from the link:

> A Python implementation of the JSON5 data format.
>
> JSON5 extends the JSON data interchange format to make it slightly
> more usable as a configuration language:
>
> - JavaScript-style comments (both single and multi-line) are legal.
> - Object keys may be unquoted if they are legal ECMAScript identifiers
> - Objects and arrays may end with trailing commas.
> - Strings can be single-quoted, and multi-line string literals are
>   allowed.

Usage is consistent with python's built in json module:

```
>>> import json5
>>> json5.loads('{"key1": "{my special value,}",}')
{u'key1': u'{my special value,}'}
```

It does come with a warning:

> **Known issues**
>
> - Did I mention that it is SLOW?

It is fast enough for loading start up config etc.

Answer (score 10):

In python you can have trailing commas inside of dictionaries and lists, so we should be able to take advantage of this using **ast.literal_eval**:

```
import ast, json

str = '{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2",}'

python_obj = ast.literal_eval(str) 
# python_obj is {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}

json_str = json.dumps(python_obj)
# json_str is '{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}'
```

However, JSON isn't *exactly* python so there are a few edge cases to this. For example, values like *null, true, false* don't exist in python. We can replace those with valid python equivalents before we run the eval:

```
import ast, json

def clean_json(str):
  str = str.replace('null', 'None').replace('true', 'True').replace('false', 'False')
  return json.dumps(ast.literal_eval(str))
```

This will unfortunately mangle any strings that have the words *null, true, or false* in them.

```
{"sentence": "show your true colors"}
```

would become

```
{"sentence": "show your True colors"}
```

Comment: Mangling of the words null, true, or false in a string is one heck of a downside, so thanks for highlighting it.

Answer (score 8):

Strip the commas before you pass the value in.

```
import re

def clean_json(string):
    string = re.sub(",[ \t\r\n]+}", "}", string)
    string = re.sub(",[ \t\r\n]+\]", "]", string)

    return string
```

Comment: This might look okay, but it'll mangle inputs like `'{"foo": ",}"}'`.

Comment: Technically there would need to be a space in there, but yes, `", }"` would get mangled.

Comment: Why have such a complicated regexp? Just use `',\s*}'` and `',\s*]'`. Then again, this method mangles strings wnich is bad. The JsonComment package isn't much better as it uses a method similar to this.

Comment: No. You do not parse formats that allow nested elements using regular expressions. -1

Comment: @jpmc26 They're not parsing the whole tree, just a single piece of syntax which itself has no nesting. The issue is not the nesting but the matching of the quotes to determine they're not in a string which is possible, but painful.

Comment: @Cramer It fails on this JSON: `{"key1": "{my special value, }"}` ([tio demo](https://tio.run/##hc7NCsIwDAfwe58i5LIOhyDeBj6JHWPOqNOuLf0Qxuiz10532M0cEv4hP4iZ/EOrY0rDaLT1YImxK92gl9Sp9um04s7bQd3LmkGuX4BTPty7cOFYnUF4YYVqdhErwKWt4i8QzSKajfgSSz5Yte4YM3l4vnmomPFF0wFrwHmcwBnqh07Cu5OBKogYi7JM6QM)). You do *not* make assumptions about the contents of complex formats like JSON. It's always a bad idea. Just don't do it. Use a properly tested parser and save yourself the heartburn.

Comment: Also, `string` is a [standard module](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/string.html). `s` would be a better variable name.

Comment: You didn't read my comment did you? It's the being-inside-a-quote that's the issue. Is there a situation that breaks that is NOT inside a string?

Answer (score 5):

### Easy to solve with [python-rapidjson](https://pypi.org/project/python-rapidjson/):

*(This is particularly relevant if you're doing scripting on VSCode `settings.json` or similar, which often generates+tolerates invalid json, comments in json, etc.)*

```py
import rapidjson

# From string: use rapidjson.loads
rapidjson.loads(
    raw_string, parse_mode=rapidjson.PM_COMMENTS | rapidjson.PM_TRAILING_COMMAS
)

# From file: use rapidjson.load
rapidjson.load(
    "file.json", parse_mode=rapidjson.PM_COMMENTS | rapidjson.PM_TRAILING_COMMAS
)
```

Answer (score 4):

Cobbling together the knowledge from a few other answers, especially the idea of using `literal_eval` from @Porkbutts answer, I present a wildly-evil solution to this problem

```py
def json_cleaner_loader(path):
    with open(path) as fh:
        exec("null=None;true=True;false=False;d={}".format(fh.read()))
    return locals()["d"]
```

This works by defining the missing constants to be their Pythonic values before evaluating the JSON struct as Python code. The structure can then be accessed from `locals()` (which is yet another dictionary).

This should work with both Python 2.7 and Python 3.x

**BEWARE** this will execute whatever is in the passed file, which may do anything the Python interpreter can, so it should **only ever be used on inputs which are known to be safe** (ie. don't let web clients provide the content) and probably not in any production environment.
This probably also fails if it's given a very large amount of content.

---

Late addendum: A side effect of this (awful) approach is that it supports Python comments within the JSON (JSON-like?) data, though it's hard to compare that to even friendly non-standard behavior.

Comment: This is a bad answer that should never be used, but technically will work. +1 only because you did include a disclaimer.

Comment: Thanks - I'm quite proud of how horrible it is!

Answer (score 1):

If I don't have the option of using any external module, my typical approach is to first just sanitize the input (i.e. remove the trailing commas and comments) and then use the built-in JSON parser.

Here's an example that uses three regular expressions to strip both single-line and multi-line comments and then trailing commas on the JSON input string then passes it to the built-in `json.loads` method.

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python

import json, re, sys

unfiltered_json_string = '''
{
    "name": "Grayson",
    "age": 45,
    "car": "A3",
    "flag": false,
    "default": true,
    "entries": [ // "This is the beginning of the comment with some quotes" """""
        "red", // This is another comment. " "" """ """"
        null, /* This is a multi line comment //
"Here's a quote on another line."
*/
        false,
        true,
    ],
    "object": {
        "key3": null,
        "key2": "This is a string with some comment characters // /* */ // /////.",
        "key1": false,
    },
}
'''

RE_SINGLE_LINE_COMMENT = re.compile(r'("(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?")|(?:\/{2,}.*)')
RE_MULTI_LINE_COMMENT = re.compile(r'("(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?")|(?:\/\*(?:(?!\*\/).)+\*\/)', flags=re.M|re.DOTALL)
RE_TRAILING_COMMA = re.compile(r',(?=\s*?[\}\]])')

if sys.version_info < (3, 5):
    # For Python versions before 3.5, use the patched copy of re.sub.
    # Based on https://gist.github.com/gromgull/3922244
    def patched_re_sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0):
        def _repl(m):
            class _match():
                def __init__(self, m):
                    self.m=m
                    self.string=m.string
                def group(self, n):
                    return m.group(n) or ''
            return re._expand(pattern, _match(m), repl)
        return re.sub(pattern, _repl, string, count=0, flags=0)
    filtered_json_string = patched_re_sub(RE_SINGLE_LINE_COMMENT, r'\1', unfiltered_json_string)
    filtered_json_string = patched_re_sub(RE_MULTI_LINE_COMMENT, r'\1', filtered_json_string)
else:
    filtered_json_string = RE_SINGLE_LINE_COMMENT.sub(r'\1', unfiltered_json_string)
    filtered_json_string = RE_MULTI_LINE_COMMENT.sub(r'\1', filtered_json_string)
filtered_json_string = RE_TRAILING_COMMA.sub('', filtered_json_string)

json_data = json.loads(filtered_json_string)
print(json.dumps(json_data, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

Answer (score 0):

json5 is pretty good by using
import json5 as json

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).