# Python can't parse JSON with extra trailing comma

Tags: python, json, parsing, runtime-error

This code:

```
import json
s = '{ "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", }'
json.loads(s)
```

produces this error in Python 2:

> ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 16 (char 15)

Similar result in Python 3:

> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 16 (char 15)

If I remove that trailing comma (after `"value2"`), I get no error. But my code will process many different JSONs, so I can't do it manually. Is it possible to setup the parser to ignore such last commas?

Comment: You can't fix the source to produce valid JSON?

Comment: @Kingsley this is for user input in an online console. When there are many records in JSON dictionaries and you remove last of them, you get a trailing comma and can easily forget it... So, it's better to automate such small things.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Another option is to parse it as YAML; YAML accepts valid JSON but also accepts all sorts of variations.

```
import yaml
s = '{ "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", }'
yaml.load(s)
```

Comment: Wow, that's simple and amazing, thanks! I just donut that YAML is a superset of JSON. It should be also mentioned that YAML parsing is much slower, but it's appropriate for rare user input parsing.

Comment: Yaml is not without issues, though - I'd better suggest you use the JSON5 library to avoid pitfalls like the Norway problem, whitespace hell, ...

Comment: @exyi link: [The Norway Problem](https://hitchdev.com/strictyaml/why/implicit-typing-removed/)

Comment: Any YAML parser that can strictly parse according to YAML 1.2 specification will no longer have Norway Problem, as since YAML 1.2 (released in 2009) only "true" and "false" are parsed as boolean: https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/ext/changes/#changes-in-version-12-revision-120-2009-07-21

Answer (score 5):

JSON specification doesn't allow trailing comma. The parser is throwing since it encounters invalid syntax token.

You might be interested in using a different parser for those files, eg. a parser built for [JSON5 spec](https://json5.org) which allows such syntax.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed, I'm looking for such a parser for a superset of JSON.

Answer (score 3):

It could be that this data stream is [JSON5](https://json5.org/), in which case there's a parser for that: https://pypi.org/project/json5/

This situation can be *alleviated* by a regex substitution that looks for `", }`, and replaces it with `" }`, allowing for any amount of whitespace between the quotes, comma and close-curly.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '{ "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", }'
>>> re.sub(r"\"\s*,\s*\}", "\" }", s)
'{ "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2" }'
```

Giving:

```
>>> import json
>>> s2 = re.sub(r"\"\s*,\s*\}", "\" }", s)
>>> json.loads(s2)
{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
```

EDIT: as commented, this is not a good practice unless you are confident your JSON data contains only simple words, and this change is not corrupting the data-stream further.  As I commented on the OP, the best course of action is to repair the up-stream data source.  But sometimes that's not possible.

Comment: You shouldn't use regex to parse JSON. This "solution" could change data, eg. the JSON could contain a string `", }"`.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a regex to find and remove all commas with `]` `}` followed in the json, but the ones in strings will be skipped.

it seems to work fine and fast.

```py
import re, json

s = r'''
[
    123, true, false, null,
    {
        "\n\\\",]\\": "\n\\\",]\\",
        "\n\\\",}\\": "\n\\\",}\\",
    },
]
'''

r = json.loads(re.sub(r'("(?:\\?.)*?")|,\s*([]}])', r'\1\2', s))

print(r)  # [123, True, False, None, {'\n\\",]\\': '\n\\",]\\', '\n\\",}\\': '\n\\",}\\'}]
```

Comment: Wow, this is really hardcore yet cool! 

Answer (score 0):

That's because an extra `,` is invalid according to [**JSON** standard](http://www.json.org).

> An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs. An object begins
>   with { (left brace) and ends with } (right brace). Each name is
>   followed by : (colon) and the name/value pairs are separated by ,
>   (comma).

[image]

If you really need this, you could wrap python's json parser with [jsoncomment](https://pypi.org/project/jsoncomment/). But I would try to fix JSON in the origin.

Comment: That's obvious :) But anyway there is a need of processing such wrong JSONs. To my mind, it should be a popular question with a simple solution.

Comment: I have seen jsoncomment, as far as I know it uses regexes and corrupts strings with nested specific symbols. I mean, it will remove comma in value-string here: `'{"foo": ",}"}'`

Answer (score -1):

I suspect it doesn't parse because "it's not json", but you could pre-process strings, using regular expression to replace `, }` with `}` and `, ]` with `]`

Comment: That's true, but such preprocessing will corrupt strings with these symbols. Consider this example: `'{"foo": ",}"}'`

Comment: True, if that's an expected input.

Comment: Exactly. Don't use regex to parse HTML, don't use regex to parse JSON. What you're looking for is an extension language of JSON, which is JSON5. Your files are written in JSON5, so just use a parser for it.

Answer (score -1):

How about use the following regex?

```
s = re.sub(r",\s*}", "}", s)
```

Comment: This will mostly work, but such preprocessing will corrupt strings with specific symbols. Consider this example: `'{"foo": ",}"}'`

Comment: @AivanF. You are right. But basically you are facing invalid JSON. I think there won't be a perfect solution.

Comment: I'm sure it is :) JavaScript and Python parse trailing comma without any problems, so, it just depends on the parser. Lazar suggested using JSON5 parser, I think this is the best option.

Comment: JSON5 is a superset which means the string generated from JSON5 may be incompatible with JSON. Anyway, it depends on your situation. If you just need to parse, I think it is OK.