# Creating python object from json

Tags: python, json

I have json file with such information

```
{
  "cars" : [{
    "model" : " BMW",
    "gas" : 100,
  },
  {
    "model" : "LADA",
    "gas" : 150
  },
  {
    "model" : "SUZUKI",
    "gas" : 70
  }]
}
```

and following class

```
class GasCar(Car):
    def __init__(self, model=None, gas=None):
        super(GasCar, self).__init__()
        self.gas = gas
        self.model = model
```

how can I create class object and transfer data from json to class instance?

I tried this

```
car = GasCar()
s = json.dumps(car)
s = json.dumps(car.__dict__)
```

Comment: can you share what you have tried so far

Comment: I am confused, are you trying to transfer data from GasCar() to JSON, or from JSON to GasCar?

Comment: from json to GasCar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON cannot be parsed by python `json` module because of the trailing comma in `100,` you may refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44913891/3939318) answer if you want to solve that. 
But assuming that the json is as follows:

```
import json
class GasCar():
    def __init__(self, model=None, gas=None):
        super(GasCar, self).__init__()
        self.gas = gas
        self.model = model

cars = """{
  "cars" : [{
    "model" : "BMW",
    "gas" : 100
  },
  {
    "model" : "LADA",
    "gas" : 150
  },
  {
    "model" : "SUZUKI",
    "gas" : 70
  }]
}"""

json_cars = json.loads(cars)
cars = json_cars["cars"] # gets "cars" list
```

You can create a car object like this:

```
car_object1 = GasCar(cars[0]["model"], cars[0]["gas"])
print(car_object1.model) # prints "BMW"
```

Or if you want a list of all cars:

```
car_objects = [GasCar(car["model"], car["gas"]) for car in cars]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could read the JSON object into dictionaries with `json.loads` ([Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)), and then pass the dictionaries as constructors to you class. Let me know if you need more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I love a more generic way to do this job. Gluing together python objects on the fly and serializing them to json and vice versa getting a JSON string an make a "Value-Container"-object out of it (without methods etc.) - I wonder how programmers can live without :-)

Maybe not the best code in the world and please make your suggestions, but I am doing it for 7 years now that way (runs in jython as well, performance also "ok"):
(please debug to see the structure of "po1" at the end):

```
# coding: UTF-8

import json

import types

def obj2dict(pp):
    if type(pp) is types.TupleType:
        olist=[]
        for p in pp:
            olist.append(obj2dict(p))
        return tuple(olist)
    if type(pp) is types.ListType:
        olist=[]
        for p in pp:
            olist.append(obj2dict(p))
        return olist

    if type(pp) is types.DictionaryType:
        odict={}
        for k,val in pp.items():
            odict[k]=obj2dict(val)
        return odict
    if type(pp) is types.InstanceType:
        odict={}
        for m in pp.__dict__:
            val=getattr(pp,m)
            odict[m]=obj2dict(val)
        return odict

        for m in dir(pp):
            if not m.startswith("_"): 
                val=getattr(pp,m)
                odict[m]=obj2dict(val)
        return odict
    return pp

class CONT:pass

def toFloat(inp):
    return float(inp.replace(",",".")) 


def dict2obj(pp):
    if type(pp) is types.ListType:
        olist=[]
        for p in pp:
            olist.append(dict2obj(p))
        return olist
    if type(pp) is types.DictionaryType:
        oinst=CONT()
        for (k,v) in pp.items():
            val=dict2obj(v)
            setattr(oinst,k,val)
        return oinst
    try:
        pp=toFloat(pp)
    except:pass
    return pp

def dumps(pp):
    return json.dumps(obj2dict(pp)) #,ensure_ascii=False)
def loads(pp):
    return dict2obj(json.loads(pp))  #,ensure_ascii=False))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    jstring="""{
  "cars" : [{
    "model" : " BMW",
    "gas" : 100
  },
  {
    "model" : "LADA",
    "gas" : 150
  },
  {
    "model" : "SUZUKI",
    "gas" : 70
  }]
}"""
    po1=loads(jstring)
    po=CONT()
    po.model="Toyota"
    po.gas=88
    print dumps(po)
```

Comment: ... I found jsonpickle, who is aiming to same. Maybe the better way.