# Verify multiple nodes in JSON?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Here is my Json data

```
{
    "DateCreated": "2019-07-26T10:25:27.1326123Z",
    "CachedEntity": false,
    "ToolsTitle": null,
    "Profile": false,
    "MenuItems": [{
            "SubMenuItems": [{
                    "SubMenuItems": [],
                    "Title": "Sub Menu Item1",
                    "IsAuthorized": true,
                }, {
                    "SubMenuItems": [],
                    "Title": "Sub Menu Item2",
                    "IsAuthorized": true,
                }
            ],
            "Title": "Menu Item1",
            "IsAuthorized": true
        }, {
            "SubMenuItems": [{
                    "SubMenuItems": [],
                    "Title": "Sub Menu Item3",
                    "IsAuthorized": false,
                }, {
                    "SubMenuItems": [],
                    "Title": "Sub Menu Item4",
                    "IsAuthorized": true,
                }
            ],
            "Title": "Menu Item2",
            "IsAuthorized": true
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to verify values in `MenuItems` list.

e.g. 
`IsAuthorized` value is `False` for `Sub Menu Item3`.

```
"Title": "Sub Menu Item3" , "IsAuthorized":false
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: its not even valid json?

Comment: @brentertainer Using Python Script I want to verify above Json. I need to verify that Node "IsAuthorised" value is "False"  when "Title" value is "Sub Menu Item3"

Comment: @NemoMeMeliorEst Why? What is wrong?

Comment: @NemoMeMeliorEst it is 100% valid JSON. It is just not a valid python dict and those two things are different.

Answer (score 2):

You can select all `SubMenuItems` that satisfies: `IsAuthorized = True` with list comprehension:

```
out = [sub_menu_Items for sub in data["MenuItems"]
       for sub_menu_Items in sub["SubMenuItems"] if not sub_menu_Items["IsAuthorized"]]

print(out)
# [{'SubMenuItems': [], 'Title': 'Sub Menu Item3', 'IsAuthorized': False}]

# To match the expected output:
out = [{k: full_dict[k] for k in ('Title', 'IsAuthorized')} for full_dict in out]
print(out)
# [{'Title': 'Sub Menu Item3', 'IsAuthorized': False}]
```

If you need to load data from a `.json` file, you can use the following:

```
import json
from jsoncomment import JsonComment

with open("filename.json", "r") as f:
    parser = JsonComment(json)
    data = parser.load(f)
```

Note: The comma at the end of the list in the `.json` file is not supported by `json.load()`. One solution might be to use [`jsoncomment`](https://pypi.org/project/jsoncomment/) as suggested in this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23705304/can-json-loads-ignore-trailing-commas).

Comment: Out of curiosity what is the JsonComment for? Couldn't you just do `data = json.load(f)`?

Comment: The comma at the end of the lists in the `.json` file raises an error using `json.load`. I take it from this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23705304/can-json-loads-ignore-trailing-commas)

Comment: Gotcha. Nice answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion with a generator:

```
data = {'DateCreated': '2019-07-26T10:25:27.1326123Z', 'CachedEntity': False, 'ToolsTitle': None, 'Profile': False, 'MenuItems': [{'SubMenuItems': [{'SubMenuItems': [], 'Title': 'Sub Menu Item1', 'IsAuthorized': True}, {'SubMenuItems': [], 'Title': 'Sub Menu Item2', 'IsAuthorized': True}], 'Title': 'Menu Item1', 'IsAuthorized': True}, {'SubMenuItems': [{'SubMenuItems': [], 'Title': 'Sub Menu Item3', 'IsAuthorized': False}, {'SubMenuItems': [], 'Title': 'Sub Menu Item4', 'IsAuthorized': True}], 'Title': 'Menu Item2', 'IsAuthorized': True}]}
def results(d):
   if "IsAuthorized" in d:
      yield {i:d.get(i) for i in ['Title', 'IsAuthorized']}
   for a, b in d.items():
      if isinstance(b, dict):
         yield from results(b)
      elif isinstance(b, list):
         for i in b:
            yield from results(i)

result = list(results(data))
```

To find instances when `IsAuthorized` is `False`:

```
final_results = [i for i in result if not i['IsAuthorized']]
```

Output:

```
[{'Title': 'Sub Menu Item3', 'IsAuthorized': False}]
```