# python Linebreak with json dic?

Tags: python, json

I want to make dic with check date

So I made

```
import json
import sys
import datetime

def check():
    with open('menu.json', encoding='utf-8') as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)
        print(str(data)) # or f"{data}"

check()
```

with this json

```
{
    "1": [
        "Date 1 Food.",
    ],
    "2": [
        "Date 2 Food",
    ],
}
```

But how can I line break I tried json.load.dumps but not works...

and how can I makes output different by date with json? 1,2 is different days

Comment: are you looking for [`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html) ?

Comment: Your JSON is invalid. Unlike in Python commas at the end of a sequence are not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

your code works!
you need to correct your json file. You have two erros on json format:

- after of last element on array, you must not put comma,
- after of last value of json, you must not put comma.
  Please, can you try using this new `menu.json` file

```
{
    "1": [
        "Date 1 Food."
    ],
    "2": [
        "Date 2 Food"
    ]
}
```

Comment: my menu json is pretty long can I make automatically delete commas, so python can understand please?

Comment: can you check this solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23705304/can-json-loads-ignore-trailing-commas

Comment: then I got this error AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'pprint'

Comment: with open('menu.json', encoding='utf-8') as json_file:
        data = JsonComment(json)
        data = json.load(json_file)
        print(data.pprint)